# How would one go about Gating content through ownership of an NFT?

Tags: nft, token, nami-wallet

The question is the title, I want to gate access to a URL based on the presence of a specific token in their wallet.

I assume this would be done through a wallet browser plugin? I've heard that this can be done through ***Nami*** wallet but would like some more information if anyone can help please?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Nami wallet documentation, it says how to interact with the wallet using web-browser, for example you can run window.cardano.enable(), there is a command for queryng UTXOs.. i have not been able to make it work, but yes the one that query the address.. then you can query the adress using blockfrost, and check the UTXOs sitting in that adress.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)